# Mixpanel alias not working

Tags: android, mixpanel

I have been trying to put mixpanel.alias using the following approaches:-

**Approach 1**

-> Identify by Mixpanel distinct id on app launch if user has not logged in and userId is not known else identify by userId on app launch itself.

-> On Successful user sign in calling alias like:
            **`mixpanel.alias(userId, null)`**

-> Then calling **`mixpanel.identify(userId)`**

**Result** Not working

---

**Approach 2**

-> On Successful user sign in calling alias like:
            **`mixpanel.alias(userId, null)`**

-> Then calling **`mixpanel.identify(userId)`**

**Result** Not working

---

**Approach 3**

-> Identify by Mixpanel distinct id on app launch if user has not logged in and userId is not known else identify by userId on app launch itself.

-> On Successful user sign in calling alias like:
            **`mixpanel.alias(userId, null)`**

**Result** Not working

---

**Approach 4**

-> -> Identify by Mixpanel distinct id on app launch if user has not logged in and userId is not known else identify by userId on app launch itself.

-> On Successful user sign in calling alias like:
            **`mixpanel.alias(userId, mixpanel.distictId())`**

-> Then calling **`mixpanel.identify(userId)`**

**Result** Not working

---

**Approach 5**

-> -> Identify by Mixpanel distinct id on app launch if user has not logged in and userId is not known else identify by userId on app launch itself.

-> On Successful user sign in calling alias like:
            **`mixpanel.alias(userId, mixpanel.distictId())`**

**Result** Not working

Could some one please let me know what mistake I am making?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After calling `mixpanel.alias(userId, mixpanel.distictId())`, does this work? -> `mixpanel.identify(mixpanel.distictId())`

It seems that identify can only take a distinctId as a parameter according to [this reference](http://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-android/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics/MixpanelAPI.People.html#identify-java.lang.String-).